# Using Custom Controls, with dependency properties in an Itemscontrol datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a polar diagram using MVVM. The radial axis is wind speed and radial angles is wind direction. I can create the radial circles (ellipses) and the radial speed axis labels. For the angular lines (like wheel spokes) I created a custom control that was simply a line with a textblock at the end (giving the angular axis value). However, I can not get my program to set the properties of this custom control and therefore you cannot see them on the canvas (though they are there but the default length is zero and default text is null)?

OK, So my diagram.xaml is as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:DiagramViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Viewbox x:Name="myView"
             Stretch="Uniform"
             StretchDirection="Both">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Height="400" Width="400"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Right" Value="{Binding Right}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="{Binding Bottom}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EllipseItem}">
                        <Ellipse Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                                 StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" 
                                 StrokeDashArray="{Binding StrokeDashArray}"
                                 Height="{Binding Height}"
                                 Width="{Binding Width}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GridLineItem}">
                        <View:GridLineComponent Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                Length="{Binding Path=Length, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                GridHeight="{Binding Path=GridHeight, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                LineColour="{Binding Path=LineColour, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                TextColour="{Binding Path=TextColour, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                RenderTransform="{Binding RenderTransform}"
                                                RenderTransformOrigin="{Binding RenderTransformOrigin}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TextBlockItem}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                                   Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                                   FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

My viewmodel (DiagramViewModel), as well as other things, contains the following method to create these lines:

```
private void CreateAngularLines(double originMargin)
    {
        IList<GridLineItem> angularLine = new List<GridLineItem>();

        double increment , angularGridlineCount, angle, height, width;

        if (this.minorAngularIncrement == null)
            increment = (double)this.majorAngularIncrement;
        else
            increment = (double)this.minorAngularIncrement;

        angularGridlineCount = 360 / increment;
        height = 200;//half the length of the canvas
        width = 200;

        for (int i = 0; i < angularGridlineCount; i++)
        {
            angularLine.Add(new GridLineItem());

            angle = i * increment;
            if (angle == 0 || angle == 180)
                angularLine[i].Text = angle.ToString("000");
            else if (angle < 180)
                angularLine[i].Text = "G" + angle.ToString("000");
            else
                angularLine[i].Text = "R" + (360 - angle).ToString("000");

            angularLine[i].Length = height - originMargin;
            angularLine[i].GridHeight = height;
            angularLine[i].LineColour = this.LineColour;
            angularLine[i].TextColour = this.TextColour;

            angularLine[i].Left = width - 18;
            angularLine[i].Top = 0;
            angularLine[i].Right = width;
            angularLine[i].Bottom = height;
            angularLine[i].ZIndex = 1;

            angularLine[i].RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 1);
            angularLine[i].RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(angle, 0, 0);
        }

        Points.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = angularLine });
    }
```

The GridLineItem class is a simple holder class with the following:

```
public class GridLineItem
{
    public GridLineItem()
    {
        this.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 1);
        this.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0, 0, 0);

        this.Left = double.NaN;
        this.Right = double.NaN;
        this.Top = double.NaN;
        this.Bottom = double.NaN;
    }

    public Brush LineColour { get; set; }
    public Brush TextColour { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double GridHeight { get; set; }
    public Point RenderTransformOrigin { get; set; }
    public Transform RenderTransform { get; set; }

    public int ZIndex { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
    public double Right { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Bottom { get; set; }
}
```

Now this is where I think I am going wrong. The GridlineComponent.xaml.cs file contains the following:

```
public partial class GridLineComponent : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public GridLineComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    public GridLineComponent(string text, double length, double gridHeight) : this()
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Length = length;
        this.GridHeight = gridHeight;
    }

    public Brush LineColour
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(LineColourProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LineColourProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LineColour");
        }
    }
    public Brush TextColour
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(TextColourProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextColourProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TextColour");
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                SetValue(TextProperty, "");
            else
                SetValue(TextProperty, value); //"\u00B0";

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }
    public double Length
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LengthProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LengthProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Length");
        }
    }
    public double GridHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(GridHeightProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridHeightProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GridHeight");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextColourProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextColour",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(GridLineComponent),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush), OnItemsPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LineColourProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LineColour",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(GridLineComponent),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush), OnItemsPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(GridLineComponent),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnItemsPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LengthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Length",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(GridLineComponent),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(double), OnItemsPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridHeightProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "GridHeight",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(GridLineComponent),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(double), OnItemsPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridLineComponent source = d as GridLineComponent;
        // Do something...
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Basically this GridLineComponent is not following the rules of MVVM. But I think that is ok here as it is such a basic type. The xaml for it is simply a grid containing a line and a TextBlock. The line's Y2 and stroke  attributes are binded to the xaml.cs (Length and LineColour respectively) and so too are the textblock's foreground and text attributes (TextColour and Text respectively).

From what I have read, these lines should draw but do not. I think it may have something to do with the dependency properties or because of the empty OnItemsPropertyChanged handler. ALso, when the program is run, only the non argument constructor, for the GridlineComponent.xaml.cs is accessed (non of the properties are set)?

Comment: Have you tried looking for the lines via Snoop WPF? That program is often quite helpful for debugging WPF binding and visual problems. It may be that your lines are generated but being placed somewhere you can't see them.

Comment: Thanks for the response NextInLine and I will definitely have a look at your suggested tool (thanks).The lines are definetly generated as the gridlinecomponent (non argument) constructor is called. However, properties are not set? So they all have a line length of 0, text is null etc. I can't check until tonight (boring day job!!!!), but I have a feeling it is because the dependencdy property may be called but this does not relay onto the associated property (I thought it would, but is this something I have to do in the OnItemsPropertyChanged handler?)

Comment: @greenbeast If your chart is circular shouldn't this line `angularLine[i].RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 1);` be point `0.5, 0.5`, ie. the center of the chart? Also, although it won't make any visible difference, you don't need the property change notification stuff on your `GridLineComponent` class as all of that will be handled by the dependency properties.

Comment: Thanks Steve, you can do that, but it is better if the 'spokes' don't go to centre of diagram but start at  say a 10knot speed radial. Otherwise the angular lines look really messy in centre and it is difficult to read any (a big black psychedelic splodge!). I have already successfully created the diagram, using the gridlinecomponent, but I am now trying to modify it to be MVVM. So the notification handler was just the reminance of that (and my laziness ;).